# How can I convert AI to HTML & CSS to use in ASP.Net Application

Tags: html, css, asp.net, adobe-illustrator

In my firm, one of my colleague who is a graphic designer had designed some pages for our new Application (in Adobe illustrator). These are in AI format. We are going to develop the Application in ASP.Net as Web Application (Forms). We want to have the same design as in AI. How can it be achieved? We thought of converting the AI to html but that will be of no use to us as it will generate html with some divs and image tags but we have buttons, text fields, and other tools as well. What could be the best way to achieve the html files. Do we need to hire a web designer or graphic designer with knowledge of html and css for this purpose or is there any software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to hire a Front-end Developer to convert it to a web page. I would not recommend any software as the code will certainly be low quality.

If the budget permits, hire a good dev with good knowledge of performance, as it will be worth it.